# Retrofit 2 - Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Tags: android, json, api, retrofit

i need to load json response into a spinner. this codes work on another activity. for example i load this on first.class and it works , so i copy and paste the code to second.class but it shows an error "EXPECTED BEGIN_ARRAY BUT WAS OBJECT"

here's my code :

Json response :

```
{
"STATUS": "SUCCESS",
"MESSAGE": "BOTTLE_SIZE",
"DATA": [
    {
        "ID_BOTTLE": "1",
        "NAME_BOTTLE": "350 ML",
        "BOTTLE_VALUE": "350",
        "BOTTLE_IMAGE": "http://128.199.120.151/admin_refil/media/bottle/WhatsApp_Image_2018-08-30_at_3.51_.42_PM_.jpeg"
    },
    {
        "ID_BOTTLE": "2",
        "NAME_BOTTLE": "500 ML",
        "BOTTLE_VALUE": "500",
        "BOTTLE_IMAGE": "http://128.199.120.151/admin_refil/media/bottle/WhatsApp_Image_2018-08-30_at_3.51_.45_PM_.jpeg"
    },
    {
        "ID_BOTTLE": "3",
        "NAME_BOTTLE": "750 ML",
        "BOTTLE_VALUE": "750",
        "BOTTLE_IMAGE": "http://128.199.120.151/admin_refil/media/bottle/WhatsApp_Image_2018-08-30_at_3.51_.44_PM_.jpeg"
    },
    {
        "ID_BOTTLE": "4",
        "NAME_BOTTLE": "1 Liter",
        "BOTTLE_VALUE": "1000",
        "BOTTLE_IMAGE": "http://128.199.120.151/admin_refil/media/bottle/WhatsApp_Image_2018-08-30_at_3.51_.43_PM_.jpeg"
    }
]
```

}

Json pojo :

```
public class ApiInformationModel {

@SerializedName("STATUS")
@Expose
private String success; //object

@SerializedName("MESSAGE")
@Expose
private String message;

@SerializedName("DATA")
@Expose
private List<InformationData> data;

public String getSuccess() {
    return success;
}

public void setSuccess(String success) {
    this.success = success;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public List<InformationData> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(List<InformationData> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public class InformationData
{
    //bottle Size
    @SerializedName("ID_BOTTLE")
    @Expose
    private String idBottle;

    @SerializedName("NAME_BOTTLE")
    @Expose
    private String namebottle;

    @SerializedName("BOTTLE_VALUE")
    @Expose
    private String bottleValue;

    @SerializedName("BOTTLE_IMAGE")
    @Expose
    private String bottleImage;

    public String getIdBottle() {
    return idBottle;
}

    public void setIdBottle(String idBottle) {
    this.idBottle = idBottle;
}

    public String getNamebottle() {
    return namebottle;
}

    public void setNamebottle(String namebottle) {
    this.namebottle = namebottle;
}

    public String getBottleValue() {
    return bottleValue;
}

    public void setBottleValue(String bottleValue) {
    this.bottleValue = bottleValue;
}

    public String getBottleImage() {
    return bottleImage;
}

    public void setBottleImage(String bottleImage) {
    this.bottleImage = bottleImage;
}

}
```

this is how i call my model :

```
public void loadBottleSize(final String bottleSizePosition) {
    informationInterface = ApiHandler.getApi(signupActivity.this).create(InformationInterface.class);
    Call<ApiInformationModel> signUpApi = informationInterface.getBottleSize();
    signUpApi.enqueue(new Callback<ApiInformationModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ApiInformationModel> call, Response<ApiInformationModel> response) {
            try {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (response.body().getSuccess().equals("FAILED")) {
                        Toast.makeText(signupActivity.this, response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        List<ApiInformationModel.InformationData> stateItems = response.body().getData();
                        List<String> listSpinner = new ArrayList<String>();

                        bottleList = new String[stateItems.size()];

                        for (int i = 0; i < stateItems.size(); i++){
                            bottleList[i] = stateItems.get(i).getBottleValue();
                            listSpinner.add(stateItems.get(i).getNamebottle());
                        }

                        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(signupActivity.this,
                                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listSpinner);
                        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        bottleSize.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }

                } else {
                    try {
                        Converter<ResponseBody, ApiError> converter = ApiHandler.getApi(signupActivity.this).responseBodyConverter(ApiError.class, new Annotation[0]);
                        ApiError error = converter.convert(response.errorBody());
                        Toast.makeText(signupActivity.this, "ini errornya " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(signupActivity.this, response.errorBody().string(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(signupActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ApiInformationModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(signupActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i've found the answer, i just need to add @Header on my interface.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your data is an `ApiInformationModel` object that contains a list of `InformationData`, so you have to change :

```
List<ApiInformationModel.InformationData> stateItems = response.body().getData();
```

by :

```
ApiInformationModel model = response.body().getData();
List<ApiInformationModel.InformationData> stateItems = model.getData();
```